# How to create new column with parts of the sentence from another column of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

I want to classify the sentence whether it contains `cat` or `dog` or `None`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'comment': ['this is a dog', 'beautiful dog', 'nice cat!', 'this is a tree']})
```

How to create a new column called 'label' which have the following values?

```
df['label'] = ['dog','dog','cat', None]
```

Required output:

```
          comment label
0   this is a dog   dog
1   beautiful dog   dog
2       nice cat!   cat
3  this is a tree  None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way `findall`

```
df['label'] = df.comment.str.findall('|'.join(['cat','dog'])).str[0]
Out[10]: 
0    dog
1    dog
2    cat
3    NaN
Name: comment, dtype: object
```

Or

```
r='(cat|dog)'
df['label'] = df.comment.str.extract(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def animal(comment):
    x = re.findall('cat|dog',comment)
    if x:
        return x
    else:
        return None

df['label'] = df['comment'].apply(animal)
```

this could work even if both occur